# How can I allow the cursor to continue moving immediately after clicking the trackpad?

Tags: trackpad, customization

I have a Macbook, though I assume this behavior occurs on all of Apple's newer trackpads (the multitouch ones where the entire trackpad acts as a button).

For a split second after clicking the trackpad, the cursor won't move (try it!), even if you continue sliding your finger across it. This probably improves usability in some areas (like double clicking), but I don't like it. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

### Edit:

I went to a local Best Buy, and every single Macbook had the same behavior. The pause is for only a split second. If you try spam-clicking as you move your finger across the trackpad, does the cursor move at all? If you click fast enough, it won't move.

Comment: This doesn't happen with mine.

Comment: I don't see  what you're seeing on my end.

Comment: Just so people don't think you're crazy, I can repro this on my 2010 MacBook Pro. It's subtle, but it happens. And unfortunately, I don't know of any way of disabling it.

Comment: @KyleCronin, if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. With everyone I've met in person, the behavior is quite obvious once I've demonstrated it. And all newer trackpads seem to exhibit this behavior.

Comment: I don't see this happening with my 2011 MBP

Answer (score 1):

I tried moving the curser with my left-hand, and clicking with my right as I dragged. Nothing unexpected happened; The curser changed temporarily during the click then reverted.

Comment: If you use a single finger, and spam your way across the trackpad, does your cursor move at all?

Comment: Of course. It works like normal.

Comment: I notice a Tracking Speed slowdown (by half perhaps), but otherwise I can continue to move it during, immediately after a click, whenever.

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't a problem in practice. Your brain gets all the little nuance and adjusts to these refinements with ease. Most come to depend on them and other hardware / OS starts to feel wrong. ( just as you do at present )

If you have exquisite motor control, you will end up with the tracking setting very high. The demo macs might be set up even slower than the default to prevent surprise to people using them on the less than ideal store setting.

Set the double click speed to max and the tracking to max and see if you can immobilize the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

It does do this exactly as you say. A way around it is to enable 3 finger dragging, and then instead of clicking, just add 2 more fingers. It will essentially act as a click & hold but it won't pause.